# Why does a deployed Empty MVC4 project have errors and references to DefaultConnection Strings?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I can create an Empty MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2012. Add a simple controller and view, then deploy to Azure. Opening the website from Azure produces an error:

```
Connection string "DefaultConnection" was not found.
Line 2:       if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
Line 3:      {
Line 4:          WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId",
Line 5:                                                   "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
Line 6:      }

Source File: c:\DWASFiles\sites\pre\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\_AppStart.cshtml    Line: 4
```

Why is an Empty Project trying to reference Websecurity/Database/etc.?

Why can't I find this code any where in my project with a global search?

Any help would be extremely appreciated. I'm losing my mind I think.

Comment: I found the problem. I had some files in the root from a previous deployment that weren't being removed when I deployed. Completely not code related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had some files in the root from a previous deployment that weren't being removed when I deployed. Completely not code related.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your test website is inheriting membership provider from machine.config. Try adding this elements to your `<system.web>` element in web.config

```
<membership>
  <providers>
      <clear />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
      <clear />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<profile enabled="false">
   <providers>
       <clear />
     </providers>
</profile>
```

also add this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It created a different error- No Default Membership Role provided. It's really strange, somewhere in this project Membership is being instantiated and I can't figure out where. Cheers!

Comment: One additional detail that may help- it runs fine on my local machine, it's only when I deploy it that it breaks (Azure or AWS). It doesn't matter if locally I use Debug or Release mode, they always work locally.

Comment: OK- I think I found the problem. I had some files in the root from a previous deployment that weren't being removed when I deployed. Completely not code related. Thank you for your suggestions and help.

Comment: Excellent, glad you fixed it.